# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException while adding an element to ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#

an "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" error gets thrown when adding a string to an ObservableCollection. The message says: Element not found " (the quotation mark is part of the message). Whats wrong with my code? Adding a string to an OvserveableCollection shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: If you don't include some code, all anybody can do is guess

Comment: Adding a string won't throw that. We need code. It's likely thrown from the object you are getting the string from but it 100% has nothing to do with adding the string. Share useful code and we can help

Comment: @angelsix If there was something observing the ObservableCollection that threw this error, then you would get this error when you added a string to an ObservableCollection<string> - but we need the code to assist further Bob_Foo...

Comment: Good point. My presumption is the error was thrown on this line of code though and not from a listener as surely the OP would state that line instead. But we are just guessing due to lack of code right now 

Comment: @Bob_Foo `(Start DeviceWatcher and register Added event)` The error is VERY LIKELY in the code you have omitted in this comment. WE CANNOT HELP YOU WITHOUT THE CODE!! Please create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if the code is too long, or cannot be shared for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the problem. In fact, the ObservableCollection wasn't part of the problem. I was simply using a wrong method to get the app's dispatcher which doesen't rutern null but throws a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when not found (or whatever problem occurs). 
So, the thread is pointless and should be deleted.

Comment: delete it then...?